# How do you manually set a logged in Identity User?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity with an ADFS server. For development purposes, I want to avoid using the ADFS server when I'm in a network environment where I can't reach the ADFS server. That's why I added a simple controller action in my HomeController that manually sets the currently logged in user:

```
#if DEBUG
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "tester"));

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        return Redirect("Home/Index");
    }
#endif
```

And the Owin Configuration method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
            });
    }
```

Commenting out the part where I use WsFederation Authentication is no problem, that way there is no link to my current ADFS server.

The problem: When I'm redirected to the Home/Index action (that has the Authorize attribute), ASP.NET Identity doesn't recognize my ClaimsPrincipal as a valid login, so I'm redirected to the Home/Login action, which creates a loop between Home/Login and Home/Index constantly.

My question: how do I make ASP.NET accept the ClaimsPrincipal created above as a valid login?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem with you approach - the cookie is not set, so the user information is not preserved across the HTTP requests. Your approach works only within a single call (there are uses for that, but not for you)

You can still use `IAuthenticationManager` from OWIN to set the cookie:

```
#if DEBUG
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LogIn()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("ApplicationCookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Testy McTestface"));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "testUser"));

        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);

        return Redirect("Home/Index");
    }
#endif
```

You will need nuget packages `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`, 
`Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`. See more explanations in my [blog-post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/) about authentication with AD

You will also need to make sure `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` is configured correclty:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider(),
            CookieName = "ApplicationCookie",
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
            });
    }
```

Especially pay authentication to `AuthenticationType` value - it must match the value in `ClaimsIdentity` constructor. Otherwise cookie will not be set, or you won't be able to log-out.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

For some reason, it still doesn't set the cookie. It might be a case of accidentally using the same named classes in different nuget packages. Or maybe my Owin Configuration file is wrong. I updated my question with how my Owin Configuration looks just in case.. I'm heading out of work now so I can't try again until tomorrow.

Comment: Works great, thanks! I noticed that this answer is pretty much independent from ADFS, so I edited your code to what my final solution was. Hopefully it's simple enough for anyone else needing this to just copy and paste into their projects.